# Can't start virhs network: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall

I am installing Minishift and part of the [installation](https://docs.okd.io/latest/minishift/getting-started/setting-up-virtualization-environment.html#kvm-driver-networking) requires to configure `virsh` network.
The status is `inactive`:

```
root@ubuntu-aws:~# virsh net-list --all
 Name                 State      Autostart     Persistent
----------------------------------------------------------
 default              inactive   yes           yes
```

I tried to start it but I received an error:

```
root@ubuntu-aws:~# virsh net-start default
error: Failed to start network default
error: internal error: Failed to apply firewall rules /sbin/iptables -w --table filter --insert INPUT --in-interface virbr0 --protocol tcp --destination-port 67 --jump ACCEPT: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

I am running ubuntu on AWS and all the external traffic is currently open.

```
root@ubuntu-aws:~# uname -a && lsb_release -a
Linux ip-172-31-27-9 4.4.0-1057-aws #66-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 3 12:49:47 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

**EDIT:**

```
root@ubuntu-aws:~# iptables -L -t filter
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-FIREWALL  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-FIREWALL  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain KUBE-FIREWALL (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets */ mark match 0x8000/0x8000
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu! Can you [edit] your question and post the output of `iptables -L -t filter`?

Comment: @MrShunz The answer is updated

Comment: Maybe it because I don't have interface named `virbr0` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the Amazon EC2 I was using doesn't support nested VM.
I tried to install the `virsh` network on my ubuntu VMware and enabled the `Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI` field in the CPU properties and I was able to do so.

I also needed to fix some networking issues I had so I added my interface `ens33` to the `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
root@ubuntu:~/minishift-1.32.0-linux-amd64# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens33
iface ens33 inet dhcp
```

And [disabled](http://www.techpository.com/ubuntu-16-04-disableenable-network-manager/) the Network manager because it was erasing the resolv.conf file each time:

```
systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
systemctl disable NetworkManager.service
```

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me on a SuSE system when I switched from NetworkManager to suse's OWN network manager.  I had to restart libvirtd, even after rebooting three times.

Something eventually changed in libvirtd.

sudo service  libvirtd restart

other people having this error also needed

sudo mobprobe tun

Comment: this was the solution on Manjaro - restart `libvirtd` then in `virsh` start the `default` network